# jQuery autocomplete source function event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The jquery `source` function is defined with two parameters `request` and `response`. Is there a way to get hold on the `event` that calls this function? Looking at the jquery code it swallows the event in the call trace without passing it on to the `source` call.

Using plain `window.event` works for IE and Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: why do you want the event?

Comment: i want to display the full list if one item is selected and arrow keys are used. Currently filtering by the selected term